# Why are my R functions not loading when I install my package from Github?

Tags: r, github, r-package, pkgdown

I am working on an R package. It was on my GitHub, but after fiddling with pkgdown to get a fancy website, the package no longer works. Specifically, the functions within it are no longer accessible, even after loading the package:

```
> remotes::install_github("joeystanley/barktools")
> library(barktools)
```

The package seems to load fine.

```
> ?bark
```

The help for the bark function loads fine.

```
> bark(100)
# Error in bark(100) : could not find function "bark"
```

Can anyone help me figure out what happened and where I went wrong?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] barktools_0.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] prettyunits_1.1.1 ps_1.3.3          fansi_0.4.1       withr_2.2.0       rprojroot_1.3-2   packrat_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4     
 [8] assertthat_0.2.1  R6_2.4.1          backports_1.1.8   cli_2.0.2         curl_4.3          remotes_2.1.1     rstudioapi_0.11  
[15] callr_3.4.3       tools_4.0.2       glue_1.4.1        xfun_0.15         compiler_4.0.2    processx_3.4.3    pkgbuild_1.1.0   
[22] knitr_1.29
```

Comment: You aren't exporting any functions. Since you're using roxygen, you can add `#' @export` within that function's roxy block, regenerate the help pages (`devtools::document(...)`?), and try loading it again. (The first hint is that your `NAMESPACE` contains no functions.) You can probably get it for now with `bark:::bark` (triple-colon).

Comment: A good ref: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#exports

Comment: Thank you @r2evans! That resolved it. I don't know why I didn't need to do that before… still learning things…

Comment: `devtools::load_all` by default exports all functions regardless of `NAMESPACE`. This was intentional, allegedly because `load_all` is primarily intended for development (and not production), so it seemed more appropriate to have direct access to all functions. (Refs: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/pull/142, https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/258, https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1998). You can always reproduce this locally with `devtools::load_all(..., export_all=FALSE)`.